# XML Header in PHP breaks code highlighting in VIM, SVN, etc

Tags: php, xml, syntax-highlighting

This is not a serious issue, but a recurring annoyance. I have a PHP class that implements several XML involved routines, in one of these I declare the header like:

```
$XML_Header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><document></document>";
```

This breaks syntax highlighting in VIM about 1/3 of the time, and in SVN all of the time. For organization reasons I don't want to move this piece to the bottom of the file, is there a way I should be escaping this code? Should I include it from another file? Is there another/better way?

Comment: Since when does Subversion have syntax highlighting? Sounds weird.

Comment: I get why it's happening, the "?>", and I can break it up with "?".">" but this feels pretty 'hacky', was hoping someone knew of a better way off the top of their head.

Comment: Emil: I was referring to the SVN repo browser, and whichever JS(?) library it uses. (For us: WebSVN)

Comment: What version of vim?  This doesn't happen to me..

Comment: Happens to me on Debian vim 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as an answer as it works, isn't pretty, but gets things working. Credit to the original poster.

Split up the trailing symbols of ?> to be seperate

```
$XML_Header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?'.'>';
```